# Property retain in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

Ok simple question but can't find an answer..

I need to pass my viewcontroller to an method "saveinfo" within a class which is called when the button is pressed, how to make viewcontroller visible to "saveinfo" method so i can use it there?

Ok i'll add the whole class. Basicaly I need to get the textfield information when the button is pressed. But i can't get access to textFields nor TableControll variables in my saveinfo method.

```
@implementation Settings

- (id)init: (TableViewController*) TableControll {
  NSMutableArray *textFields = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    UITextField *textField = nil;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f+(i*35), 120.0f, 30.0f)];
        textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [textField setBorderStyle:(UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect)];
        [TableControll.view addSubview:textField];

        [textFields addObject:textField];
        [textField release]; textField = nil;
    }
    UITextField *textName = textFields[0];
    textName.placeholder = @"Vardas";

    UITextField *textNo = textFields[1];
    textNo.placeholder = @"Telefonas";
    textNo.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    UITextField *textPin = textFields[2];
    textPin.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    textPin.placeholder = @"Pin";

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(150, 20, 160, 30);
    [button setTitle:@"Advanced settings" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [TableControll.view addSubview:button];
    UIButton *save = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    save.frame = CGRectMake(150, 60, 160, 30);
    [save setTitle:@"Save settings" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [TableControll.view addSubview:save];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(goAdvanced)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [save addTarget:self action:@selector(saveInfo)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return self;
}

-(void)goAdvanced {
    AppDelegate *newControll = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [newControll ChangeController];
}

-(void)saveInfo {

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        UITextField *tempTxtField=[_textFields objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"do it %@",tempTxtField.text);
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: give us some more information: what is the structure of application? 
Controller A -> Class B or them are in 2 class not related?
What is you main controller? Does it retain the controller you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the `NSMutableArray` as ivar to your class:

```
@implementation TableControll {
    NSMutableArray *_textFields;
}

- (id)init: (TableViewController*) tableControll {
    _textFields = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

    //init the textfields
    //and add it as subview
}

// skipping the rest of the implementation

-(void)saveInfo {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        UITextField *tempTxtField=[_textFields objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"do it %@",tempTxtField.text);
    }                 
}  
@end
```

you should check if you could reuse the `UITextFields` or have to init the `NSMutableArray` every time again. It seems you don't use ARC, but you shouldn't write something like `[textField release]; textField = nil;`. You want to release the object to decrement the counter, but do not set it to `nil` (except in dealloc).